# Why decryption failed on Oreo 8.1 after update (keys not properly upgraded?)?

Tags: updates, encryption, 8.1-oreo

After updating, Pixel 2 can't decrypt user data. Seems like some keys are not updated properly. Flashing  older firmware doesn't help because of Google's new anti-rollback feature.

How to fix that and decrypt my data? Device is unlocked.

```
    walleye:/ $ logcat
--------- beginning of system
01-12 01:30:26.698   682   682 I vold    : Vold 3.0 (the awakening) firing up
01-12 01:30:26.698   682   682 V vold    : Detected support for: ext4 vfat
01-12 01:30:26.703   682   692 I vold    : e4crypt_initialize_global_de
01-12 01:30:26.704   682   692 D vold    : Key exists, using: /data/unencrypted/key
01-12 01:30:26.718   682   692 D vold    : Added key 556838879 (ext4:702f703661b6e047) to keyring 120297969 in process 682
01-12 01:30:26.718   682   692 D vold    : Added key 950968792 (f2fs:702f703661b6e047) to keyring 120297969 in process 682
01-12 01:30:26.718   682   692 D vold    : Added key 943429884 (fscrypt:702f703661b6e047) to keyring 120297969 in process 682
01-12 01:30:26.718   682   692 I vold    : Wrote system DE key reference to:/data/unencrypted/ref
01-12 01:30:26.763   682   692 D vold    : e4crypt_init_user0
01-12 01:30:26.763   682   692 D vold    : Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys
01-12 01:30:26.764   682   692 D vold    : Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce
01-12 01:30:26.764   682   692 D vold    : Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/de
01-12 01:30:26.768   682   692 E vold    : begin failed, code -62
01-12 01:30:26.768   682   692 D vold    : Upgrading key: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0
01-12 01:30:26.772   682   692 E vold    : upgrade_key failed, code -33
01-12 01:30:27.057   682   690 D vold    : Disk at 7:0 changed
01-12 01:30:27.114   682   690 I chatty  : uid=0(root) /system/bin/vold identical 1 line
01-12 01:30:27.201   682   690 D vold    : Disk at 7:0 changed
```

Comment: Also mention your device in question